# Keeping Specific Text line in a cell for specific starting letters with excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple text lines in a cell on Column A. I want to keep only one line starting with specific letters (see: Picture 1). For example, first I would like to check if it has a line starting with "MB". If it has then I would like to keep only that line. If it doesn't has then it will search consecutively letters "SA" then "PQ" and so on. I am trying to implement this in Excel VBA.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opA9p.png)

I have found some clue using built in function. For example

*Remove everything after the first comma

`=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1)`

*Remove everything before the second occurrence comma

`=RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ",", CHAR(9), 2), LEN(A1)- FIND(CHAR(9), SUBSTITUTE(A1, ",", CHAR(9), 2), 1) + 1)`

However, those are not the solution I am looking for. I would highly appreciate if anyone can help me.

Regards,
Oliver

Comment: Have you considered regular expressions? Looks like that might be helpfull in your situation. Otherwise, `SPLIT()` your string into array can also work quite nicely.

Comment: @Jvdv Could you please explain a bit? I have a variable range therefore I would like to implement it in Macro.

Comment: Regular expressions will test your string for specific combination of characters and will return the matched result. Furthermore, `SPLIT()` would chop up your string using a delimiter (linebreak in your case) and store them into an array which you could loop through. Both options can quite easily be implemented within an UDF (User Defined Function) to be used on dynamic ranges. There are multiple examples around I bet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Google-Sheets***

I know you didn't ask about `Google-Sheets` but in this case it could be a nice way out too (I'm no GS expert whatsoever, but tried something that seems interesting for you)

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\b"&TRANSPOSE($B$1:$D$1)&"[^\s]+"))),"")
```

This way you can extend the parts you interested in (extend the range `B1:D1`), + it will give you all the regex matches available in the input.

Drag the formula down.

***Excel***

Within Excel you could think about an UDF using REGEX, here is a quick example:

```
Function GetRegEx(str As String)

Dim regex As Object
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Dim MyArr() As String
MyArr = Split("MB,PQ,SA", ",")

For X = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)
    With regex
        .Pattern = "\b" & MyArr(X) & "[^\s]+"
        .Global = True
    End With
    Set matches = regex.Execute(str)
    If matches.Count > 0 Then
        GetRegEx = matches(0).Value
        Exit Function
    End If
Next X
End Function
```

Call it like `=getregex(A2)` and drag down...

[image]